# OpenVPN Routing

Tags: networking, ip, routing, openvpn

I have an environment where we have two locations connected through a site-to-site VPN using two NETGEAR UTM150 appliances.

I have an OpenVPN server at Site A.
I have a web server located at Site B.

I would like clients who VPN to the OpenVPN Server at Site A to be able to access the webserver at Site B.

Site A Lan:  10.0.1.0/24
Site A NETGEAR Appliance:  10.0.1.1
Site A OpenVPN Server: 10.0.1.10
Site A Test Computer:  10.0.1.101

Site B Lan:  10.0.2.0/24
Site B NETGEAR Appliance:  10.0.2.1
Site B Web Server:  10.0.2.50
Site B Test Computer: 10.0.2.101

OpenVPN LAN:  10.0.200.0/24
OpenVPN Server Lan Address 10.0.200.1
OpenVPN Client: 10.0.200.2

I am able to ping and access the Site B Web Server from the Site A and B Test computers.
I am able to ping the Site B Web Server from the OpenVPN Server.
I am able to ping the Site A Test Computer from the OpenVPN Server.
I am able to ping the Site A Test Computer from the OpenVPN Client.
I am able to ping the Site A NETGEAR Appliance from the Site B Web Server.
I am able to ping the Site A OpenVPN Server from the Site B Web Server.

I am NOT able to ping the Site B Test Computer or the Site B Web Server from the OpenVPN Client.

When performing a traceroute from OpenVPN Client to Site B Web Server the following occurs:

1. It hits the OpenVPN Server at 10.0.200.1
2. It hits the SITE A NETGEAR UTM150 at 10.0.1.1
3. It then does not go over the NETGEAR Appliances Site to Site VPN Link, but tries to find 10.0.2.50 over the internet.
4. The requests then timeout.

I know there is a route I am missing somewhere.  But I cannot figure out where it should go and what it should look like.

I would be happy to provide additional information if requested.

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE #1**

From OpenVPN Client (10.0.200.2) to Site B Webserver (10.0.2.50)

```
C:\Windows\system32>TRACERT.EXE 10.0.2.50

Tracing route to 10.0.2.50 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1   115 ms    86 ms    69 ms  10.0.200.1
  2    88 ms    59 ms   102 ms  10.0.1.1
  3   243 ms   187 ms    71 ms  ISP Address [***.***.***.***]
  4   171 ms   103 ms    84 ms  96.***.***.***
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
--- SNIP ---
 30     *        *        *     Request timed out.

Trace complete.
```

From Site A Test Computer (10.0.1.101) to Site B Web Server (10.0.2.50)

```
C:\Windows\system32>TRACERT.EXE 10.0.2.50

Tracing route to 10.0.2.50 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.0.1.1
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3    37 ms    31 ms    46 ms  10.0.2.50

Trace complete.
```

I will make a diagram and see if I can update this post later today.  But perhaps these traceroutes might shed some light.

Comment: How do you know that it tries to find 10.0.2.50 over the internet? Can you show the actual output of the trace route? Making a diagram would help too.

Comment: Your NETGEAR Appliance (10.0.1.1) is responsible for sending the package to the next router in your case to the "internet router". Seems that it doesn't know where to send 10.0.2.50 so it sends it to the default gateway (at least thats my guess since I don't know the config). If the Appliance has routing capabilities you need to setup the proper routes/interfaces if it doesn't you need to set up a router to properly route the packages between the different subnets. Alternatively you could put them on the same subnet.

Comment: I'm curious if the NETGEAR appliance has some kind of shadow routing going on.  It will route anything within the 10.0.1.0/24 subnet over the Site to Site VPN, but perhaps it isn't routing packets from the 10.0.200.0/24 subnet.  There is nothing in its routing table that shows anything related to the 10.0.2.0/24 subnet.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "shadow routing" or if I didn't understand you but "routing" the packets "within" the same subnet isn't really "routing". Or in other words: you don't need a router if the clients talking to each other are within the same subnet. As I said, a simplyfied diagram showing layer 1 including the logical data (IP adresses etc.) should help to uncover the problems much better.

Comment: I have solved the problem.  Good luck to the rest of you.

Comment: It would be nice if you could add an answer with your solution.